# UI Testing for Power Platform on Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, ui-automation, power-platform

Tester on our team has created automated testing via Visual Studio, which uses chrome in order to perform tasks on an environment on Power Platform. The tests work successfully locally. This is EASYREPO.

I have created the following pipeline with YAML.

This Pipeline fails with "Chrome driver does not exist".

I've followed Classic, and YAML based Microsoft Documents, and i cannot get anywhere with it.

##[error] [ERROR] The file D:\a_temp\*PROJECTNAME*chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

I can confirm that the solution does have chrome driver exactly in the file it says it is not in....

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'
parameters:
- name: BrowserType
displayName: "Test on Chrome"
type: string
default: Chrome
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.90/chromedriver_win32.zip" -OutFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/chromedriver_win32.zip;
Expand-Archive -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/chromedriver_win32.zip -DestinationPath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/chromedriver;
$env:webdriverpath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/chromedriver"
$env:path += ";$env:webdriverpath"
displayName: 'Download and install ChromeDriver'

- powershell: |
# Set agent screen resolution to 1920x1080 to avoid sizing issues with Portal
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1080 -Force

# Wait 10 seconds
Start-Sleep -s 10

# Verify Screen Resolution is set to 1920x1080
Get-DisplayResolution
ignoreLASTEXITCODE: true
displayName: "Agent Screen Size"
- task: NuGetCommand@2
displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
inputs:
restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
- task: VSBuild@1
displayName: 'Build Power Apps Test Automation Solution'
inputs:
solution: '**\*.sln'
- task: VSTest@2
displayName: 'Run Power Apps Test Automation Tests via Chrome'
condition: or(eq('${{ parameters.BrowserType }}', 'Chrome'), eq('${{ parameters.BrowserType }}', 'All'))
inputs:
testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
testAssemblyVer2: 'DLL HERE'
searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
uiTests: true
```

Comment: I have now gotten rid of the Chrome error. But the tests just do not run at all. Can anybody advise?

Comment: The driver (and all artifacts) shouldn't be referenced from local path, should it?